# Retrieve StoreID for MailItem (within Outlook Selection)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, outlook, vsto, outlook-2003

I need to iterate through the [`MailItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem) items within a [`Selection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.selection.aspx) and read their `EntryID` and `StoreID` values in order to be able to retrieve the mail items again later (for background processing through Redemption). Is there a way of retrieving the `StoreID` for a `MailItem` directly?

I know that it may be retrieved through the `StoreID` property of its parent `Folder`; however, this seems quite inefficient, since it must instantiate (and release) the COM object for the parent folder for each item. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

**Edit**: I cannot use the [`Selection.Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.selection.parent%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property since it was only introduced in Outlook 2007, and I need to support Outlook 2003. Additionally, [Sue Mosher](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=1777) states:

> The `Parent` object of a `Selection` would be an `Explorer`, so you could use `Selection.Parent.CurrentFolder.Store`.

However, when one performs a search across “All Outlook Items”, it seems that `CurrentFolder` would always point to a search folder within the main store, which is typically the Exchange mailbox:

```
\\Mailbox - <username>\search folders\All Outlook Items
```

Since the search may match items in other stores, the `CurrentFolder.Store` would not necessarily correspond to the store of the selected items, making this approach unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the parent for each item, could you get the parent once by using [`Selection.Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.selection.parent.aspx)?

Comment: I'm targetting Outlook 2003; the `Selection.Parent` property was only introduced in Outlook 2007. And I don't think that all mail items in a `Selection` would always share a common `StoreID`. Searches, for example, may span multiple stores.

Comment: Right - if the `Parent` targets multiple stores, you must use the [`Item.Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff867611.aspx) for each item, there is not a more efficient way.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I'll upvote you once I have enough reputation.